# Can't set linkAttributes on TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, tttattributedlabel

Using TTTAttributedLabel, with my code:

```
NSString *contentText = @"some text here foo bar";

[self.content setText:contentText afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
    return mutableAttributedString;
}];
self.content.linkAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor],
                               NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] };
NSRange range = [self.content.text rangeOfString:@"foo bar"];
[self.content addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"action://load-foo"] withRange:range];
[self.content setNeedsDisplay];
```

Everything works perfectly, in terms of tapping the range text and performing an action, however, the only thing that doesn't seem to work is the text colour. Am I using `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` correctly with the lib?

EDIT:

By, "doesn't work", is that the underlined text stays grey, and not red like I've set it above.

Comment: Are you deploying on lower iOSes than 6?

Comment: @Andrea Nope, iOS8 and above

Comment: Use NSAttributeString and default text rendering objects it will be a lot easier replace label with UITextField or TextView and check for data detectors

Comment: You should assign `linkAttributes` before setting the text or adding links to the label.

Comment: This last comment was actually the proper answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encounter the same problem before, after struggled for quite some time and still did not find out the reason, I drop out of your mentioned solution and come up with the following method:

```
NSString *contentText = @"some text here foo bar";
NSString* matchString = @"foo bar";
NSRegularExpression *mentionExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:matchString options:NO error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [mentionExpression matchesInString:contentText
                                                  options:0
                                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [contentText length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
        NSString *mentionString = [contentText substringWithRange:matchRange];
        NSArray *keys = @[(id) kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, (id) kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName
        ];
        NSArray *objects = @[[UIColor redColor], @(kCTUnderlineStyleNone)];
        NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{keys : objects};

        [self.yourlabel addLinkWithTextCheckingResult:match attributes:linkAttributes];
    }
    self.yourlabel.delegate = self;

//Then overwrite the delegate method for the link click actions
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithTextCheckingResult:(NSTextCheckingResult *)result {
    //do whatever you need
}
```

The advantage of this solution is you can add as many customised link style as you wish.

Of course another possible solution if you insist using `addLinkToURL` is to change `TTTAttributedLabel` source code to change the default link color.