# Custom style of Address link in UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uitextview, nsdatadetector

I'm seeing something odd inside of `UITextView`. The `UITextView` is able to detect my address, but I'm not able to style the text, even though I'm able to style phone numbers & web links.

See the code below (I've tried `tintColor` & `linkTextAttributes` - both seem to apply to things other than the Address link)

```
let t = "One Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014 some other text yeah www.google.com 123-555-1212 One Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014"
let a = NSAttributedString(string: t)

self.textView.attributedText = a
self.textView.isEditable = false

self.textView.textColor = .green
self.textView.tintColor = .blue

self.textView.dataDetectorTypes = [.link, .address, .phoneNumber]

let linkAttributes: [String : Any] = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.red,
    NSAttributedStringKey.underlineColor.rawValue: UIColor.orange,
    NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle.rawValue: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]

self.textView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
```

[image]

As you can see, the Address is underlined & clickable (clicking takes me to maps), but the red color isn't applied to it, *even though* other things detected by the data detector are picked up.

Thoughts?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166812/cant-set-linkattributes-on-tttattributedlabel

Comment: Have you tried setting linkTextAttributes before dataDetectorTypes? Might be a race?

Comment: @ThomasDeniau I tried that - no luck. Good suggestion though.

Comment: @JasmeetKaur That solution has to do with TTTAttributedLabel. I would rather not use that.

Comment: You should file this at bugreport.apple.com. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that setting the attributed text properties for the textview overrides the link attributes for the address, so my workaround is to manually set the attributed text for addresses. That worked for me for removing the underline entirely.